# Docker Build - GPG error Phusion Passenger Enterprise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile, passenger, phusion

Our docker build using passenger enterprise has stopped building.

We have the following error:

> GPG error: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/enterprise_apt xenial Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 2

At this stage in the `Dockerfile`

```
ADD passenger-enterprise-license /etc/passenger-enterprise-license
RUN echo deb https://download:<OUR_KEY>@www.phusionpassenger.com/enterprise_apt xenial main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" passenger-enterprise nginx-extras
```

Docker logs:

> Step 7/39 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" passenger-enterprise nginx-extras
>    ---> Running in cfb74f74a227
>   Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
>   Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
>   Ign:3 https://www.phusionpassenger.com/enterprise_apt xenial InRelease
>   Get:4 https://www.phusionpassenger.com/enterprise_apt xenial Release [23.0 kB]
>   Err:5 https://www.phusionpassenger.com/enterprise_apt xenial Release.gpg
>   The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 2

I have checked the passenger-enterprise-license and the token. They are both correct.

Have also raised github issues here: [Docker build failing Enterprise](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2061)
and here: [Docker build failing Enterprise](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker/issues/216)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phusion Passenger team member here. For anyone still experiencing this problem: unfortunately some gpg keys were not properly imported when we migrated to a new server yesterday. The issue should be resolved now, but if you are still experiencing issues, try running `apt clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt update`

This will clear the local apt cache and retry the apt update.
We are very sorry for the inconvenience caused by this.